# ERROR @wdio/appium-service: Appium exited before timeout?

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io, appium-android

[C:\Automation\NewProject\app\android\ApiDemos-debug.apk Android #0-0] » \test\specs\sample.e2e.js
[C:\Automation\NewProject\app\android\ApiDemos-debug.apk Android #0-0] Sample Test
[C:\Automation\NewProject\app\android\ApiDemos-debug.apk Android #0-0]    ✓ First Test
[C:\Automation\NewProject\app\android\ApiDemos-debug.apk Android #0-0]
[C:\Automation\NewProject\app\android\ApiDemos-debug.apk Android #0-0] 1 passing (1.8s)

Spec Files:      1 passed, 1 total (100% completed) in 00:00:11

2024-02-09T06:09:27.315Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Shutting down spawned worker

---

2024-02-09T06:09:27.317Z **ERROR @wdio/appium-service: Appium exited before timeout (exit code: null)**

---

2024-02-09T06:09:27.583Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Waiting for 0 to shut down gracefully
2024-02-09T06:09:27.584Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: shutting down

```
capabilities: [{
    // capabilities for local Appium web tests on an Android Emulator
    platformName: 'Android',
    'appium:deviceName': 'Pixel7',
    'appium:platformVersion': '12.0',
    'appium:automationName': 'UiAutomator2',
    'appium:udid' : 'emulator-5554',
    'appium:app' : path.join(process.cwd(),'app\\android\\ApiDemos-debug.apk')
}],
```

Script is passed and test is performed but at the end getting is error:
2024-02-09T06:09:27.317Z **ERROR @wdio/appium-service: Appium exited before timeout (exit code: null)**